# AcActDoc.Editor not declared

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have been teaching myself to make custom commands in AutoCAD by looking at and learning from others' code. In a recent example I've been looking at I am encountering an error that "AcActDoc" is not declared. I cannot find any documentation on this, 0 results everywhere I look. If this is a typo in the code, does anyone know what it is supposed to be? I've separated and made bold the line in question.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.DataExtraction
Imports PBHSDes.PBHSDClass
Public Class DataExtract
'Const path As String = "c:\Program Files\AutoCAD 2009\Sample\"
'Const fileName As String = "Visualization - Aerial.dwg"

<CommandMethod("extd")>
Public Sub extractData()
    'If Not System.IO.File.Exists(path + fileName) Then
    '   Dim doc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    '   Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor
    '   ed.WriteMessage(vbLf & "File does not exist.")
    '   Return
    'End If
```

**Dim Ed As Editor = AcActDoc.Editor**

```
    Dim fileRes As PromptFileNameResult
    Dim PrFileOpts As New PromptOpenFileOptions("Select File To Extract Data:")
    'PrFileOpts.SearchPath = True
    PrFileOpts.PreferCommandLine = False
    PrFileOpts.Filter = "AutoCAD Drawing files (*.dwg)|*.dwg"
    fileRes = Ed.GetFileNameForOpen(PrFileOpts)
    'you should check the status so if they cancel the dialog the method stops
    If fileRes.Status <> PromptStatus.OK Then Return
    Const outputXmlFile As String = "c:\temp\data-extract.xml"
    Dim Path As String = FileIO.FileSystem.GetParentPath(fileRes.StringResult)
    Dim filename As String = FileIO.FileSystem.GetName(fileRes.StringResult)
    MsgBox(Path & vbCrLf & filename)
    ' Create some settings for the extraction 
    Dim es As IDxExtractionSettings = New DxExtractionSettings()
    Dim de As IDxDrawingDataExtractor = es.DrawingDataExtractor
    de.Settings.ExtractFlags = ExtractFlags.ModelSpaceOnly Or ExtractFlags.XrefDependent Or ExtractFlags.Nested
    ' Add a single file to the settings 
    Dim fr As IDxFileReference = New DxFileReference(Path, Path + filename)
    de.Settings.DrawingList.AddFile(fr)
    ' Scan the drawing for object types & their properties 
    de.DiscoverTypesAndProperties(Path)
    Dim types As List(Of IDxTypeDescriptor) = de.DiscoveredTypesAndProperties
    ' Select all the types and properties for extraction 
    ' by adding them one-by-one to these two lists 
    Dim selTypes As New List(Of String)()
    Dim selProps As New List(Of String)()
    For Each type As IDxTypeDescriptor In types
        selTypes.Add(type.GlobalName)
        For Each pr As IDxPropertyDescriptor In type.Properties
            If Not selProps.Contains(pr.GlobalName) Then
                selProps.Add(pr.GlobalName)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    ' Pass this information to the extractor 
    de.Settings.SetSelectedTypesAndProperties(types, selTypes, selProps)
    ' Now perform the extraction itself 
    de.ExtractData(Path)
    ' Get the results of the extraction 
    Dim dataTable As System.Data.DataTable = de.ExtractedData
    ' Output the extracted data to an XML file 
    If dataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dataTable.TableName = "My_Data_Extract"
        dataTable.WriteXml(outputXmlFile)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcActDoc` is not a built-in object. It should be a variable in the code of which you have copied an incomplete extract. Look at the upper code you commented, `AcActDoc` and `Ed` should be declared and instantiated as `doc` and `ed`:

```
Dim doc As Document = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
Dim ed As Editor = doc.Editor
```